# export PATH=~/workspace/swift-dev/usr/bin:"${PATH}"

Tags: bash, path, terminal

Taken from 
https://swift.org/download/#linux

> export PATH=/path/to/usr/bin:"${PATH}"

how come I have to do this every time!? every session it stops the path thing, is this because I have to have administrative privledges?

Comment: have you tried editing your `.bashrc` file and including the line: `export PATH=/path/to/usr/bin:"${PATH}"`

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your `.bashrc` file and including the line:

```
export PATH=/path/to/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

then source your .bashrc with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```